# C program - values not adding to the vector in a loop

Tags: c

My apologies first that this question might be stupid. I created a vector and tried to add new elements to this vector in a loop. But it seems the loop stops at the first step. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
int n, NT=97;

double *x=malloc(NT*sizeof(double));

x[0]=0;
double dt=30;   
double utem=0.5, dx;

for (n=1;n<NT;n++)

    dx=dt*utem;
    x[n] = x[n-1] + dx;
    printf("x is %6.13f \n", (double)x[n]);
```

Here is the result: x is 15.0.
The loop stops at the first step.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include you loop in brackets:

```
int n, NT=97;

double *x=malloc(NT*sizeof(double));

x[0]=0;
double dt=30;   
double utem=0.5, dx;

for (n=1;n<NT;n++)
{
    dx=dt*utem;
    x[n] = x[n-1] + dx;
}

printf("x is %6.13f \n", (double)x[n]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can see my problem now. I am not used to adding brackets to loops.